# What's the fastest way to get an exact value for $\int_a^b{(1+x)^n dx}$?

Tags: integration

Suppose we have two integers $a$ and $b$.

What's the fastest way to get an exact value for $\int_a^b{(1+x)^n dx}$, with $n$ large?

Comment: I suppose asking Wolfram Alpha is faster than asking here.  Or do you want something other than the formula from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: @GEdgar: I was just kind of wondering, because I am considering what I think is a neat trick to doing some integrals.  I wasn't anticipating David Mitra's answer, though.  My idea might not be as worthwhile as I thought it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a substitution, $u=1+x$: for $n\ne -1$
$$
\int_a^ b(1+x)^n\,dx=\int_{1+a}^{1+b} u^n \,du={u^{n+1}\over n+1}\biggl|_{1+a}^{1+b}
={(1+b)^{n+1}\over n+1} -{(1+a)^{n+1}\over n+1} .
$$

Comment: It took 6 minutes to the answer by asking here.  How long by asking Wolfram Alpha?  The question was "the fastest way"...

Comment: Plus, he said "$n$ large", so $n \ne -1$.