# What's the fastest way to get an exact value for a product of (powers of polynomials)?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Suppose we have two integers $a$ and $b$.  Also, suppose we have polynomials in $x$, $p_k(x)$.  Finally, suppose we have a sequence of integers, where an integer in the sequence is denoted by $c_k$.

What's the fastest way to get an exact value for $\int_a^b{\left(\displaystyle \prod_k{\left(p_k(x)\right)^{c_k}}\right) dx}$, with the $c_k$s large?

This is a more complicated version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110943).  Perhaps ["What's the fastest way to get an exact value for integrate a power of a polynomial?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110968) may help with ideas.

Comment: I'd forget about the integral for a moment. And deal with the problem as computing the polynomial $$R(x) = \displaystyle \prod_k{\left(p_k(x)\right)^{c_k}}$$ which you can do using evaluation-then-interpolation. Afterwords, a definite integration of $R(x)$ should be straightforward operation.

Comment: I'd first try the question when all $c_k=1$, or when the number of polynomials is $1$ and $c_1>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd forget about the integral for a moment. And deal with the problem as computing the polynomial $$ R(x) = \displaystyle \prod_k{\left(p_k(x)\right)^{c_k}} $$
which you can do using evaluation-then-interpolation (e.g. [my other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/110976/2468)). Afterwords, a definite integration of $R(x)$ should be straightforward operation.

Another approach to compute $R(x)$ is to consider the following [Jordan block matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form): $$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
C(p_1(x)^{c_1}) && 0 && \ldots && 0 \\
0 && C(p_2(x)^{c_2}) && 0 && \ldots && 0 \\
0 && \ldots && \ldots && \ldots &&  \\
0 && \ldots && 0 && \ldots && C(p_n(x)^{c_n}) 
\end{pmatrix}$$ where $C(p_k(x)^{c_k})$ is the block companion matrix of $p_k(x)$. Then $R(x) = \operatorname{charpoly}(A)$ which can be computed using fast linear algebra methods.